# What is the magic separator between filenames in ls output?

Tags: ls, pipe, newlines

The output of `ls` (with no arguments) appears to separate filenames with linebreaks.

Evidence:

- `ls | grep foo` works as expected, with `grep` treating each filename as a separate line of input.
- `ls > files.txt; vim files.txt` --> in Vim, each file is on a separate line

And yet in the terminal the output of `ls` puts multiple files on one line, separating the filenames with spaces to make nicely aligned columns:

```
$ ls
a.txt  b.txt  c.txt
```

So my question is, how does ls do this?

Is it using some special control char to 'fake' a newline? Or does it know when its output is being piped to another command, and format its output differently in this case?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> Or does it know when its output is being piped to another command, and format its output differently in this case?

Yes. From the full manual (available through `info ls` if the documentation is installed):

> If standard output is a terminal, the
>   output is in columns (sorted vertically) and control characters are
>   output as question marks; otherwise, the output is listed one per line
>   and control characters are output as-is.

If you like the one column output, you can run

```
ls -1
```

to get it in the terminal as well.

Comment: Specifically, the function `ls` uses to determine whether or not the output is a terminal is `isatty(3)`.

Comment: Also somewhat related, if one wants to test this in a simple shell script one can run `tty -s` and check its return status.

Answer (score 11):

`ls` detects it when you pipe its output. You can see it in the documentation:

> If standard output is a terminal, the output is in columns (sorted vertically) and control characters are output as question marks; otherwise, the output is listed one per line and control characters are output as-is.

If you want each file in the output to be placed on a separate line regardless of the pipe redirection, you can use

```
ls -1
```