# Using the ls -l with a pipe how can i get it to display the 8th file in the list without the file details

Tags: linux, ls

I am looking to display the 8th file name in a directory using ls -l and pipe  for example 
ls -l | wc -1 would give me the count but what i want to have returned is the 8th file name in the directory list whatever it is. i have looked at grep and wildcards but still do not see which command would give me the result i am looking for.

Thanks

Comment: Have a read : http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 4):

try

```
ls -l | head -n 9 | tail -n 1
```

if you want only name you can use `cut` at the end

```
ls -l | head -n 9 | tail -n 1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f8
```

`tr` is to replace multiply spaces and tabs by one space

Comment: +1 for the `tr -s ' ' | cut` trick, I never thought of that for some reason - i typically use (g)awk when extracting columns.

Comment: If the filename contains multiple spaces in sequence, the returned file name will be wrong by having its spaces collapsed. And for that matter, even if the filename just contains a single space, it will not be returned in full since only field 8 is returned, which is the file name *up to its first space*. Also, you don't need `ls -l` as pointed out if you just want the filename, but you also don't even need `ls -1`; just `ls` will do (see http://superuser.com/q/424246/49184).

Comment: This also gives the wrong output on my system, since it is dependent on the lcoale for the date format. `-f9` is needed here (as also touched upon in cokedude's answer), but as I said, file names with spaces will be incorrect. `-f9-` will return fields 9 *and onwards* and be better, but then again, file names with multiple spaces in sequence will still be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is like this.

`ls -l | sed -n '9p'`

If you only want the file or directory name then use this.

`ls -l | sed -n '9p' | awk '{print $9}'`

jcubic are you sure this is what you wanted?

`ls -l | head -n 9 | tail -n 1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f8`

I would think he would want the file or directory name like this.

`ls -l | head -n 9 | tail -n 1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f9`

Answer (score 0):

```
ls | awk 'NR==8'
```

- You **don't** need `ls -l` to get 1-column output, or even `ls -1` if you are throwing output to a pipe (see e.g. [What is the magic separator between filenames in ls output?](https://superuser.com/q/424246/49184)).
- `NR==8` will only return true for line 8, and then `awk` default action is to print it.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use `-l`

> ls | head -8 | tail -1

You get file name, `ls` orders files same as `ls -l`.